# htaccess redirect, Mask external urls with internal urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-masking

I'm using a WordPress plugin that don't work properly(No External Links). I need a htaccess code for masking external links in website.

Example URL pattern is this, which is separated with /go/:
"http: //WWW.mywebsite.com/go/HTTP: //WWW.externalsite.com/one/two/..."

I want above URL redirected to this URL:
"HTTP: //WWW.externalsite.com/one/two/..."

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: @webo80 I don't know anything about htaccess.